# Connection to local host timed out

Tags: android, rest, get

I'm using an Android Emulator and trying to perform a GET request on a root document that is located on my local host and will allow me to login.

The method to login

```
     * @param rootDocumentUri        The Uri the login attempt is to be invoked against.
 * @param loginSuccessfulCallback The callback that is called if the login attempt was successful.
 * @param loginFailedCallback The callback that is called if the login attempt was not successful.
 * @param timeout           The length of time, in milliseconds, to wait for a response from the server.
 */
public void login(Uri rootDocumentUri, LoginCompletedListener loginSuccessfulCallback,
                  LoginCompletedListener loginFailedCallback, int timeout);
```

The method in use:

```
  MobileBaseUri = Address for my Uri.

         MobileApi.login(Uri.parse(MobileBaseUri), new LoginSuccessful(), new LoginFailed(), MobileSettings.getInstance().getHttpRequestTimeoutPeriod() );
```

When I attempt to login the application performs a GET on the RootDocument, but all I get back is : "HttpClient(1884): org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to /10.0.0.8:80 timed out"

The timeout is set to a minute, and the server is on my local host so I should be being blocked by any firewall..

Does anyone know what the issue could be?

Thanks.

Comment: The `localhost` address of your development machine is aliased as 10.0.2.2. See this documentation http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking

Comment: Your correct, cheers for the help.